# How to refactor class component to functional(have to rerender, got undefined )

Tags: reactjs

In IssueEdit component the main state of my app is stored(which I got from an API
call).
I pass that data to a specialized input component where issue.effort have to be
converted to string and stored as string. It works well in case of Class Component. I tried to refactor the class component to functional component and this is when the problem started. The problem is that after first render formattedValue is undefined so nothing is displayed. The input field is empty. How to make functional component behave equally as class component?

```
export const IssueEdit = () => {

const [issue, setIssue] = useState({effort: 5})
       ...
return (
  ...
        <td>
                                <NumInput
                                    name="effort"
                                    value={issue.effort}                
                                />
       </td>
  ...

                         *** Class Component ***
function format(num) {
     return num != null ? num.toString() : '';
}

export default class NumInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
      this.state = { value: format(props.value) };
      this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
   }
   onChange(e) {
      if (e.target.value.match(/^\d*$/)) {
         this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
   }
}

render() {
  const { value } = this.state;
   return (
     <input
       type="text"
       value={value}
       onChange={this.onChange}
     />
   );
  }
}

                      *** Functional Component ***

export const NumInput = ({ value }) => {
const format = (num) => {
    num != null ? num.toString() : ''
}

const [formattedValue, setFormattedValue] = useState(format(value))

const onChange = (e) => {
     if (target.value.match(/^\d*$/)) setFormattedValue(target.value)
}

return (
    <input
        type="text"
        value={formattedValue}
        onChange={onChange}
    />
 )
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this just a typo ? `onChange={onChangeValue}` should be `onChange={onChange}`.

You named your function `onChange` in the functional component but are then invoking it with `onChangeValue` which doesnt exist.

Another problem as the author commented I'll edit so everyone can see:

```
const format = (num) => {
    num != null ? num.toString() : ''
}
// what u meant
const format = (num) => {
    return num != null ? num.toString() : ''
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It was a typo, but the problem wasn't in it. The problem is the empty input field on page render.

Comment: I take this answer as a correct because it really was a typo that sneaked into my code. I forgot to return a value from a format function.

Comment: i was just setting up a codesandbox and had no idea what the problem was :D that sneaky `return` statement